# Applying default style in templated control from Generic.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

I have created a templated control in WinRT/UWP with a GridView inside of it. I created an **`ItemTemplate`** dependency property that will house the `DataTemplate` of the grid view's items, so that when the control is re-used on other pages, I have the flexibility to change the item templates in each implementation.

However, with the current code that I have, it loads the control properly but the styling is not implemented.

Here's my Generic.xaml code:

```
<Style TargetType="ctrl:CustomGridView">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid Background="Red">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ctrl:CustomGridView">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="templateProxy" Width="{TemplateBinding ItemWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ItemHeight}"  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <GridView x:Name="gridView" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                              SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" IsSwipeEnabled="False" IsTabStop="False">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=templateProxy}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=templateProxy}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </GridView>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The goal is to make the `ItemTemplate` set in Generic.xaml to be the default one, and allow to change it on different implementations of the control.

Here's how the `ItemTemplate` property is defined in the CustomGridView.cs file:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(PatientGridView), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }
```

Is there anything I should do in the CustomGridView.cs to load the default ItemTemplate? Am I missing anything?

I'll provide additional code if necessary.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include this code:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```

to your AssemblyInfo.cs file

Comment: ThemeInfo isn't showing up in IntelliSense. Note that this is a UWP (Windows 10) application.